# Walker nav remove submenu ul from a certain depth

Tags: sub-menu, walker

I want to remove `sub-menu` ul and `.menu-item-has-children` class when the menu depth is superior or egal to 2.

So, I only want a menu with 3 sub-menu at maximum. Other item children will still displayed in the menu but not in a sub menu.

With wp_nav_menu('depth' => 3) it don't append all items. So, I think I need to use a custom walker nav.

I don't know how to do it with `start_lvl`. What is the way to count depth and to remove ul and classes...

My aim is to change this menu:

- menu-item-has-children

  - menu-item-1
  - menu-item-2
  - menu-item-has-children

    - menu-item-3
    - menu-item-4
    - menu-item-has-children

      - menu-item-5
      - menu-item-6

to this menu :

- menu-item-has-children

  - menu-item-1
  - menu-item-2
  - menu-item-has-children

    - menu-item-3
    - menu-item-4
    - menu-item-has-children
    - menu-item-5
    - menu-item-6

And the unwanted behavior provides by wp_nav_menu('depth' => 3) option in wordpress

- menu-item-has-children

  - menu-item-1
  - menu-item-2
  - menu-item-has-children

    - menu-item-3
    - menu-item-4
    - menu-item-has-children

I've tried with this:

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) { 
    if($depth >= 2) {
        $output .=  '';
    } else {
        $output .= "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
    }
}
```

It near works, but it create a problem with ul inside my navmenu.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why the depth argument doesn't work?

Comment: I don't say that it doesn't work but the behavior of depth in `wp_nav_menu` just removed all menu-item after the choseen depth. In my case I want to display it but not in an other submenu.

Comment: ... it doesn't work _for what you need_. I am trying to figure out what the difference is between what you want and what `wp_nav_menu` does with the `depth` argument. I still can't really tell.

Comment: With the code that I write, I near works... But create a problem with my custom class megamenu added in an menu-item-has-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, and without testing anything, the code you've got should work but I expect that you have a number of spurious `</ul>` in your markup. You need to do nearly the same thing for the `end_lvl` method.

```
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) { 
    if($depth >= 2) {
        $output .=  '';
    } else {
        $output .= "</ul>";
    }
}
```

I don't know if that is the problem with your megamenu or not.

Comment: Yes! You're right, I didn't think about that!!! It works great know! Thanks a lot!